# Automatic login using angular-oauth2-oidc without presenting the login page

Tags: angular, oauth, angular-oauth2-oidc

I want to automatically login the user with angular-oauth2-oidc, if there is an active session on the id server. But if thats not the case, i don't want to present the login page but just have in internal state set.

I tried with

```
service.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin()
```

but that returns allways true without giving me any tokens or claims to get the user profile.

this is my config:

```
const defaultAuthConfig: AuthConfig = {
  // Url of the Identity Provider
  issuer: 'https://....net',
  tokenEndpoint: 'https://....net/oauth2/token',

   
  // URL of the SPA to redirect the user to after login
  redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/redirect',
  silentRefreshRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/redirect',

   useSilentRefresh: true,

   clientId: 'server.code',

   responseType: 'code',

   scope: 'openid profile email offline_access api',

   showDebugInformation: true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tryLogin` part just checks if you were just now redirected from the IDP to the Angular App, and if the URL contains login tokens and whatnot.

You are looking for a "silent" login right after that, before you decide you really need to ask the user to explicitly log in with a redirect flow. There are two ways to do that:

1. With `refresh_token`s if the risk (attack vectors) of `offline_access` and refresh tokens are worth it to you;
2. With a "silent iframe refresh" if [you can work around the modern browser limitiations around 3rd party cookies](https://infi.nl/nieuws/spa-necromancy/), e.g. by hosting your IDP on a subdomain of the domain that hosts your Angular app;

Regardless of which you configure, you make the library do said silent refresh by calling `this.oauthService.silentRefresh()` at the right time.

You can check [the relevant code in my sample repository](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/e49258887ce79baea500f3e6df7dd75463400368/src/app/core/auth.service.ts#L104-L146) (which you can clone and run to see it in action), for reference here's the relevant code:

```
this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument()
  .then(() => this.oauthService.tryLogin())
  .then(() => {
    if (this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken()) {
      return Promise.resolve(); // already signed in
    }
    return this.oauthService.silentRefresh()
      .then(() => Promise.resolve())
      .catch(result => {
        // Consider sending the user to the login page here.
        return Promise.reject(result);
      });
  });
```